# How do you construct a boost variant that can take an assignment of a scoped_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost

I cannot use move semantics introduced in C++11, so to emulate move semantics I occasionally use scoped_ptr and use swap explicitly to show ownership changes.

I've ran into an issue in which I don't know how to do this with the contained boost::variant types.  For simplicity sake take this naive example:

```
  #include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
  #include <boost/variant.hpp>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>

  typedef boost::variant<
                     boost::scoped_ptr<std::string>,
                     boost::scoped_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > vType;

  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     boost::scoped_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > vec = new std::vector;
     vType var;
     // How do I assign vec to var to hand off ownership and prevent 
     // recreation of the vector?
     // ??
     return 0;

  }
```

Is there anything like a `boost::swap(boost::variant, value::type)` overload or alternative that would assign the variant value using swap on the value type internal to the variant? That would be the ideal solution.

---

Things I have already considered:

I could use a shared_ptr to prevent copies, but I rather use scoped_ptr to enforce single ownership and remove the overhead of shared_ptr.

std::auto_ptr would give me the semantics I'd like but it is also easy to mistakenly make assignments and switch ownership. So far this seems like my best option, but I was intentionally staying away from it for the reason stated.

I could create a wrapper class or template for the string and vector which is used in the variant that has a copy assignment operator which internally does move like semantics, but then I might as well be using std::auto_ptr.

I could create a union (like) class instead of using boost::variant, but I wanted to take advantage of some of the tools available to me in boost with dealing with the variant type.

So any other suggestions, or good arguments for the options I did enumerated?

---

### **UPDATE**

This question is similar: [boost::variant; std::unique_ptr and copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689793/boostvariant-stdunique-ptr-and-copy)

Even though the conclusion in that question is that a non-copyable type can't be used with boost variant, I still need to solve my general usecase:  Move semantics when assigning my types to a boost::variant without the availability of C++11 rvalue semantics.

Comment: Looks to me that (pseudocode) std::swap (ptr, boost::get <scoped_ptr<vector>>(your_variant)) should work I think

Comment: biocomp, other than I found I can't use scoped_ptr because it isn't copy constructible, Using boost::get to directly retrieve a reference is a good suggestion.