# unable to return a std::vector of boost::variant of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I'm writing a small C++ module for Python. In this module I set connection to different databases. Connection to one of those databases is set like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<R::Connection> conn = R::connect("localhost", 28015);
```

After I set connection, I want to return this connection variable. The way I do it is using `vector` and `variant` (since I may return multiple things in a vector - database connection, some extra parameters etc).

This is how I define `variant` and `vector` types:

```
typedef variant<std::unique_ptr<R::Connection>,....connections to other databases> VariantData;
typedef std::vector<VariantData> vector;
```

And, finally, this is how I return a vector right after I set connection:

```
return vector{conn, ""};
```

As a result, I get a long list of errors. However, this trick works well with other clients which set connections to other databases and do not use `unique_ptr`. So, I think I need something like casting `std::unique_ptr<R::Connection>` to `Connection *` or something like that, to be able to use `conn` variable like a general pointer.

**EDIT**

With these snippets of code:

```
typedef variant<R::Connection * ,....connections to other databases> VariantData;
typedef std::vector<VariantData> vector;

... function body
... code which does not matter
std::unique_ptr<R::Connection> conn = R::connect("localhost", 28015);
return vector{move(conn),""};
```

And this is the error messages I get:

```
n file included from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17:0,
             from corm.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp: In instantiation of ‘typename   boost::enable_if<boost::is_rvalue_reference<T&&> >::type boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::convert_construct(T&&, int, mpl_::false_) [with T = std::unique_ptr<RethinkDB::Connection>; T0_ = mysqlpp::Connection*; T1 = mongo::DBClientBase*; T2 = pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>*; T3 = sqlite3**; T4 = IBPP::Ptr<IBPP::IDatabase>; T5 = RethinkDB::Connection*; T6 = const char*; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_rvalue_reference<T&&> >::type = void; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’:
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1789:62:   required from ‘boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::variant(T&&, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_rvalue_reference<T&&> >::type*, typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_const<FunctionObj> >::type*) [with T = std::unique_ptr<RethinkDB::Connection>; T0_ = mysqlpp::Connection*; T1 = mongo::DBClientBase*; T2 = pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>*; T3 = sqlite3**; T4 = IBPP::Ptr<IBPP::IDatabase>; T5 = RethinkDB::Connection*; T6 = const char*; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_rvalue_reference<T&&> >::type = void; typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_const<FunctionObj> >::type = void]’
corm.cpp:94:39:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1615:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::variant<mysqlpp::Connection*, mongo::DBClientBase*, pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct>*, sqlite3**, IBPP::Ptr<IBPP::IDatabase>, RethinkDB::Connection*, const char*>::initializer::initialize(void*, boost::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<RethinkDB::Connection>&>::type)’
             )
             ^
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1615:17: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:33:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
             from corm.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:104:24: note: static int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize(void*, boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::param_T) [with BaseIndexPair = boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >, 
>::initializer_node::param_T {aka RethinkDB::Connection* const&}’
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'corm.o' failed
make: *** [corm.o] Error 1
```

**EDIT**

This is the code (minimized)

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <rethinkdb.h>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::python;
namespace Ret = RethinkDB;

typedef variant<Ret::Connection *, const char*> VariantData;
typedef std::vector<VariantData> vector;

class ORM{
private:
    int idx;
public:
    ORM(int _idx){
      this->idx = _idx;
    }
    vector Connect(){
        if(this->idx == 8){
            std::unique_ptr<Ret::Connection> conn = Ret::connect(this->host, this->port);
            return vector{std::move(conn), ""};
        }
    }
};


struct variant_to_object:static_visitor<PyObject*>{
   static result_type convert(VariantData const& v){
      return apply_visitor(variant_to_object(), v);
   }
   template<typename T>
   result_type operator () (T const& v) const{
      return incref(object(v).ptr());
   }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(corm){   

   class_<vector>("vector").def(vector_indexing_suite<vector, true>());
   to_python_converter<VariantData, variant_to_object>();
   implicitly_convertible<Ret::Connection *, VariantData>();
   implicitly_convertible<const char*, VariantData>();   

   class_<ORM>("ORM",
     init<int>())
     .def("Connect", &ORM::Connect);

}
```

Client for rethinkdb is taken from [here](https://github.com/AtnNn/librethinkdbxx).

Comment: Maybe `return vector{std::move(conn), ""};`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, that should be `std::move`, never call `move` unqualified.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, edited. In fact, I'm confused by the use of (non-`std`) `vector` here too :-)

Comment: We are interested in the long list of errors.

Comment: I've already tried this and it does not work. By the way, in this case, how should I typedef my VariantData? Like `typedef variant<std::unique_ptr<R::Connection>...` or like typedef variant<R::Connection *,....`

Comment: I will post the list of errors in a minute.

Comment: Also, what is this `variant` type? Where did you find it? Is it in Boost? Also, is this function returning to Python? If not, then maybe Python has no real relevance to this question?

Comment: Yes, it is in boost.

Comment: Variant can only be used with copy-constructible types. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689793/boostvariant-stdunique-ptr-and-copy).

Comment: I think `using std::vector` is clearer than `typedef` to indicate bringing in namespaced entities. Plus, syntactically, it's nicer in any case. (However, I always explicitly specify things from `std` and the like, and I'd say this whole snippet is an argument for that. :P)

Comment: Can you provide a stand alone compilable (or not) example that demonstrates the issue without the irrelevant parts?

Comment: Yes, I can. But it may take some time for me to prepare. I guess about 5-10 minutes

Comment: You should have spent those 5-10 minutes to do it before wasting other people's time.

Comment: I'm going to edit the title. "vector of unique_ptr" is wrong. I'll go for "std::vector of boost::variant of std::unique_ptr". A bit pedantic perhaps, but this question does weird things with `vector`

Comment: Your variant type is declared as having a `Ret::Connection *` but you are trying to put a `std::uniqur_ptr<Ret::Connection>` into your vector. Maybe declare the variant type as taking a `std::unique_ptr`?